# Url rewriting: Redirection passing query parameter

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

With IIS 7.5 how can I redirect

```
http://localhost/en/test?id=tool-37
```

to

```
http://localhost/en/tool/37
```

I write this rule but it **doesn't work**

```
<rule name="Tool-Diseases" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.+)/test.+id=([0-9]+)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/tool/{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The URL and the QueryString are handled seperate in IIS Rewrite Module.

For example, if a request was made for this URL: http://www.mysite.com/content/default.aspx?tabid=2&subtabid=3, and a rewrite rule was defined on the site level then:

- The rule pattern gets the URL string content/default.aspx as an input
- The QUERY_STRING server variable contains tabid=2&subtabid=3.
- The HTTP_HOST server variable contains www.mysite.com.
- The SERVER_PORT server variable contains 80.
- The SERVER_PORT_SECURE server variable contains 0 and HTTPS contains OFF.
- The REQUEST_URI  server variable contains /default.aspx?tabid=2&subtabid=3

You can enter the regex to match your querystring in the "Server Variables" Section in the IIS rewrite settings.